# Missing piano sounds

Tags: digital-piano

My daughter practices at home on digital piano casio cdp-230r. She has to learn from page 38:  Op.849 (Czerny, Carl). Her problem is that she thinks that the piano "is missing some sounds" for a part of notes

[image: notes that are "missing sounds"]

Question: is it possible that the piano is not good or should we make some configurations?

Comment: It's probably in 2b, and is a simple chromatic run up from C>C initially. Every single white and black key, sequentially, an octave  higher than it looks like on the stave (8va). What exactly is she missing?

Comment: She says that she does not finds those sounds on digital piano - they do not sount at all like classic piani. At school it has classic piano, and those notes do not sound like home (using the same keys). Sorry but I have no experience with piano or music

Comment: Do you know what kind of piano you have at home, make and model? Do you know if you can change the sounds on the piano?

Comment: Piano Casio CDP-230R

Comment: Sounds like she might be noticing the quality difference between the school and home pianos. You might look at saving up for a better piano, involve her in the selection process, make it a gift to her for a holiday or birthday, and/or engage with her on having a job or doing chores to raise money for a better piano. It might help you to have a conversation with her and her piano teacher about her complaint and what can be done about it. The teacher should be able to “translate” the musical concepts for you.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://www.casio-intl.com/asia/en/emi/products/cdp230r/spec/ the unit has 48 notes maximum polyphony which I can only assume applies to both the keyboard buttons and the sound engine inside. So all the notes should sound. (Some very low end keyboards might only be able to play one or two or three notes at the same time. Yours can do much better so that shouldn't be the problem here.)

Does the PIANO/ORGAN button toggle to a better sound? There are many more piano sound options available through the TONE button as well. They are listed in the "Appendix" PDF available https://support.casio.com/en/manual/manualfile.php?cid=008006005 if you no longer have the manual.

Your keyboard you have does a have many other settings that could be affecting the sound. If your daughter can explain a little more what is wrong with the sound she hears, that might help us troubleshoot better.

Comment: She complains that, "a specific block of notes" in the right side of the piano are "too high" comparing with the classic piano

Comment: @user237329 - That sounds like a broken digital piano to me.

Comment: @user237329 Okay, thanks. Does pressing the "Split" button fix it by any chance?